# How to quickly find relations between objects and nest them

Tags: javascript, typescript

I often use code for finding related structures and nesting them, for example: we have userList(id, name) and filesList(id, name, userId). Every file belong to one user. So, I want to make generic function for finding these relations and want to get next structure as result:

```
{
  user: User,
  files: Files[]
}
```

So, I wrote these code

```
  public findRelationsAndBuildNestedStructure<ParentType, ChildType>(
    parent: {
      structures: ParentType[];
      path: string;
      resultFieldName: string;
    },
    child: {
      structures: ChildType[];
      path: string;
      resultFieldName: string;
    },
  ): Array<{
    [parent.resultFieldName]: ParentType;
    [child.resultFieldName]: ChildType[];
  }> {
    return parent.structures.map((parentObject: ParentType) => {
      const relatedChildren: ChildType[] = [];
      child.structures.map(childObject => {
        if (
          _.get(parentObject, parent.path) === _.get(childObject, child.path)
        ) {
          relatedChildren.push(childObject);
        }
      });
      return {
        [parent.resultFieldName]: parentObject,
        [child.resultFieldName]: relatedChildren,
      };
    });
  }
```

But have an error at these lines:

```
[parent.resultFieldName]: ParentType;
[child.resultFieldName]: ChildType[];
```

> TS1170: A computed property name in a type literal must refer to an
>   expression whose type is a literal type or a 'unique symbol' type.

Help me please, how could I do it? Or maybe you know another way how to find related objects?

Comment: Neither `parent` nor `child` are defined nor are literal type values. You could do something like `[name: string]: ParentType;`.

Comment: no, it's not good. At first it throw enw error 'TS2374: Duplicate string index signature.', at the second I want result with implicit fields. I mean I want to see list of feilds when check result type. But is I use [name: string] field name could be any